# Reading .txt file into a List C#

Tags: c#, list

I am new to C# coming from Python, and this piece is really confusing to me...

I have a simple .txt file with the values:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

I want to read those into a List, 1 item in list per row.  Seems easy enough but I can't figure it out.  What am I doing incorrectly?  Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

string LOG_PATH = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\source\\repos\\LoopPractice\\TextFile1.txt"
List<string> allLinesText = ReadAllLines(LOG_PATH).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, perhaps, you found the documentation to `ReadAllLines` but didn't include the full declaration.

Try this:

```
List<string> allLinesText = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(LOG_PATH).ToList();
```

`ReadAllLines` is a `static` method in the class `System.IO.File`.  If you want to simplify the above line you could add `using System.IO;` to the top of your file, then your code would become:

```
List<string> allLinesText = File.ReadAllLines(LOG_PATH).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked perfectly.  The first implementation I see uses System.Linq that I am not familiar with yet, but have heard its useful.  Thank you for showing both implementations.  I will accept this in a cpl mins when it allows me!

Comment: `System.Linq` is useful, definitely keep that around.  You'll probably run into answers to questions that don't tell you that you need it :)